# Excel: find substring and get row number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I'm looking for a way to search a column and get the first string containg a date.

Example given:

```
A1: "str"
A2: "str"
A3: 01/01/2005
A4: 01/01/2006
```

I want to get 3 from seaching column A since A3 is the first cell that contains a date.

By only using worksheet functions, not VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel dates are simply formatted numbers so if you have just text and dates you can just find the position of the first number

=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(A1:A1000),0),0)